Questions about longest sentences which meet specific characteristics
I'm very happy to see that the question Longest sentence where all characters have the same sound has been received favorably (2k views at this moment!). And I do like the answers, especially the "shishishishishishi..." one written by Tang ho.
I wonder if it's just a matter of different wording since my similar question What's the longest Chinese sentence made up of only 3rd tones? was closed because was considered opinion-based.
As you can see I have adapted my question to the accepted wording. Is it ok now? Can it be reopened? Would it be better to write a new question?

I personally don't see a problem with your question.  I guess sometimes questions are judged based on the answers they get, and the "shi shi shi shi shi..." paragraph is a clear-cut answer.
